# How make cxf-codegen-plugin generate Webservices from jakarta.xml.ws?

Tags: java, java-11, wsdl2java, cxf-codegen-plugin

Migrating from Java 8 to Java 11.

Updated cxf-codegen-plugin from version 3.2.0 to 3.3.6.

Plugin still generates Java stubs from wsdl files using packages from javax.jws.* instead of from jakarta.jws.*:

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;

/**
 * This class was generated by Apache CXF 3.3.6
 * 2020-08-12T19:22:40.406+02:00
 * Generated source version: 3.3.6
 *
 */
```

Am I getting it wrong that javax.jws is deprecated and should be changed to jakarta.jws?

And how do I accomplish code generation with desired packages?

Comment: I assume that this has not yet been implemented, maybe it would come once https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-8371 is resolved

Answer (score 11):

Issue has been resolved in [CXF-8371](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-8371)

If you upgrade to version >=4.0.0 it will generate jakarta.jws instead of javax.jws.

Answer (score 4):

Try using maven-replacer-plugin at generated-source phase, in my case I generate client files on target folder and then replace package there

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-replacer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>replace-for-jakarta</id>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>replace</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filesToInclude>target/generated/**/*.java</filesToInclude>
                        <preserveDir>true</preserveDir>
                        <replacements>
                            <replacement>
                                <token>javax.jws</token>
                                <value>jakarta.jws</value>
                            </replacement>
                        </replacements>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Seriously? That sounds like a hack, not like a solution. Is there no proper solution for this?

Comment: not yet. Ticket ist in Progress https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-8371

Answer (score 1):

in our case the configuration was like this:

```
<configuration>
                            <filesToInclude>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf/**/*.java</filesToInclude>
                            <preserveDir>true</preserveDir>
                            <replacements>
                                <replacement>
                                    <token>javax.xml.bind</token>
                                    <value>jakarta.xml.bind</value>
                                </replacement>
                                <replacement>
                                    <token>javax.annotation</token>
                                    <value>jakarta.annotation</value>
                                </replacement>
                                <replacement>
                                    <token>javax.jws</token>
                                    <value>jakarta.jws</value>
                                </replacement>
                                <replacement>
                                    <token>javax.xml.ws</token>
                                    <value>jakarta.xml.ws</value>
                                </replacement>
                            </replacements>
                        </configuration>
```

Comment: 2022-12-06 this is still viable solution

Comment: with the new version there is support for jakarta and there is no need anymore of the maven-replacer-plugin like in my comment from 2022.